# Log4jConfigurer in Spring 5.0.2

Tags: java, spring, log4j, slf4j

I was using Spring 4.X.X and used the below setup to configure Log4j. Now am upgrading it to Spring 5.0.2 where the `Log4jConfigurer` class has been removed. How can I do it in Spring 5.0.2?

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:log4j.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Log4JConfigurer` was required for non default Log4j initialisation e.g. if using a custom config file name/location but your config file is located in the default location: `classpath:log4j.properties` so you can simply remove the `Log4jConfigurer` declaration and Spring will auto discover your `log4j.properties`.

There is one possible caveat here; Spring 5 uses Log4j v2 (following Apache's EOL declaration for log4j 1.x) so as long as you are using Log4j v2 then Spring 5 will auto detect it and your `log4j.properties` file without any need to declare a `Log4JConfigurer`. If you are not currently using Log4j v2 then I think you'll need to upgrade since Spring 5 does not support the use of Log4j v1.x.

Comment: Thanks Glytching, I am using currently log4j v1.x, now upgrading to v2.10.0.  I also using org.apache.log4j.ext.SNMPTrapAppender v1.2.8 is this one also not compatible with Spring v5..0.2 ?  Am not able to find the V2.x for org.apache.log4j.ext.SNMPTrapAppender.

Comment: log4j.appender.TRAP_LOG=org.apache.log4j.ext.SNMPTrapAppender
log4j.appender.TRAP_LOG.ImplementationClassName=org.apache.log4j.ext.JoeSNMPTrapSender

Comment: I'm not aware of a Log4j2 version of SNMPTrapAppender.

Comment: In case if am going to place the log4j.properties file in a custom location then how to provide that path to Spring v5 for initialization.

Comment: See [the docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html), specifically: "Log4j will inspect the "log4j.configurationFile" system property ...".