# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/KotlinDetector while migrating from spring-core-3.2.0 to spring 4.x

Tags: java, spring, java-8, websphere-liberty

I am facing issue while migrating from spring 3.2.0 to spring 4.x

If I am using spring-core 4.x, getting exception:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/KotlinDetector while deploying to IBM Liberty server as the corresponding class is not there, this is available in spring-core-5.1.0
```

and further, if I am using "spring-core-5.1.0" jar, getting exception:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/Log4jConfigurer
```

Also, there is no such migration guide I can found for above stated issue.

In this case I left with only one option to customize the spring-core library, but when I am trying to customize, getting exception:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forRawClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/core/ResolvableType
```

While deploying to IBM Liberty Server due to some compatibility issue, even after adding the ResolvableType into customized library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log4jConfigurer in Spring 5.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48107537/log4jconfigurer-in-spring-5-0-2)

Comment: Release notes with details https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#commons-logging-setup