# Log4jConfigurer cannot be resolved

Tags: spring, log4j

I am migrating from spring version 4 to spring version 5. Getting error in org.springframework.utils.Log4jConfigurer.

The error is :
Unable to resolve symbol Log4jConfigurer

Have also tried changing apache Log4j version to 2 but error still persists.
What is the alternative for Log4jConfigurer in Spring 5? Any help.

I was using Spring 4.X.X and used the below setup to configure Log4j. Now am upgrading it to Spring 5.0.2 where the Log4jConfigurer class has been removed. How can I do it in Spring 5.0.2?

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:mylog4j.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: This can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48107537/log4jconfigurer-in-spring-5-0-2

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to define a Log4JConfigurer. Simply add log4j.properties to your classpath to configure log4j. Spring 5 will find it and you can use Log4J.
Concerning the version of Log4j I'm using version 1.2.17 in my Spring 5 project and it works perfectly.

Comment: I have added the code. So shall I simply remove the property targetClass & targetMethod?

Comment: Yes, it should work when you remove those lines. The Configurer bean is not needed anymore.

Comment: this is not working since I have a custom location for log4j. properties. (mylog4j.properties) I have updated the code above again.